# RobotFramework: No new window at last index. Please use '@{ex}= | List Windows' + new > window trigger + 'Select Window | ${ex}' to find it

Tags: robotframework

My requirement is, On click of a button in a window(parent window) it has to open a new window(popup window, child window) and I wrote a testcase for this.

But the issue is when the button on the parent window is clicked, my script fails and gives in the report/log as:

> "No new window at last index. Please use '@{ex}= | List Windows' + new
>   window trigger + 'Select Window | ${ex}' to find it."

Below is one of the userdefined keyword used in my testcase which is failing in Robot Framework:

```
Move To Chat Page
    Click Button                    Continue to ChatPage>>

    Select Window                   new
    Set Selenium Implicit Wait      6s
    Click Button                    //input[@type='submit'][@value='Continue with ChatBot']

    Set Selenium Implicit Wait      3s
    Click Element                   user.profileBean.issue
    Select From List By Value       user.profileBean.overrideIssue      2
    Click Button                    Continue to connect

    Set Selenium Implicit Wait  3s
    Select Window                   main
    Title Should Be                 XYZ
```

Below is the screenshot of the same:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using windows it's best to use a unique Id, Name, Title or the URL of the popup. In the below example I have a simple index page which creates a popup.

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>main-window</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://localhost:8090/popup/popup.html" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://localhost:8090/popup/popup.html','1496569988172','width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,left=0,top=0');return false;">Pop-up Window</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>popup-window</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     Pop!!
  </body>
</html>
```

When using the following robot script the switch between the windows is made.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Test popup
    Create Webdriver    Chrome
    Go To    http://localhost:8090/popup/
    Click Link    Pop-up Window
    Select Window    url=http://localhost:8090/popup/popup.html
    Log Title
    Select Window
    Log Title
    Capture Page Screenshot 
    [Teardown]  Close All Browsers
```

Which in this case will add the following items to the log file:

- main-window
- popup-window

Comment: I modified your script to work with internet explorer instead of chrome, and used local files instead of http.

like this: 
Select Window  url=file:///C://Users//ABC//Documents//Dummy//popup.html

but getting error as "NoSuchWindowException: Message: No window found"

Comment: The above example works also when specifying Ie, instead of Chrome. Can  your retest with the pages on a webserver? Working with local files and javascript always creates difficulties. You can create a webserver from a folder using the following command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8090` when in the directory containing the files. `SimpleHTTPServer` module is part of the default Python installation.

Comment: any solution for my main problem reported.

Comment: If the above solution does not work for you let me know what issue you have with it and I'll update the answer.